# What does inconsistent accessibility mean in C#?

Tags: c#

im trying to use this method to make my characters but i get the error:
inconsistent accessibility:return type'consoleapplication1.Enemigo' is less accesible than
method 'consoleapplication1.poringbuilder.makeporing()'
its the first time i get this error and i really dont know what to do,i have tried alot of different ways but i get the same mistake plz help >.<

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class PoringBuilder
    {
        public static Enemigo MakePoring()
        {
            return new Enemigo(15, 0, 30,15, false, false,"Poring");
        }
    }
```

this is another class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Enemigo:Personaje
    {
        public Enemigo(int Damage, int Defensa, int HP,int MP, bool Evade, bool Counter, string Nombre)
            : base(Damage, Defensa, HP,MP, Evade, Counter, Nombre)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this is the parent of all my classes

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Personaje
    {
        public int Damage;
        public int Defensa;

        public int HP;

        public int MP;
        public bool Evade;
        public bool Counter;
        public string Nombre;
        //public Personaje() { }
        public Personaje(int Damage, int Defensa, int HP,int MP, bool Evade, bool Counter, string Nombre)
        {
            this.Damage = Damage;
            this.Defensa = Defensa;
            this.HP = HP;
            this.MP = MP;
            this.Evade = Evade;
            this.Counter = Counter;
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
        }
    }
}
```

and im using it on the main program like this

```
List<Enemigo> EnemigosNoob = new List<Enemigo>();
EnemigosNoob.Add(PoringBuilder.MakePoring());
```

i hope im precise enough >.< i tried making it public and its not solving anything >.<

Comment: Sorry Juliet, seems like StackOverflow needs a better source control system.

Comment: btw its JULIO!! NOT JULIET!! XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MakePoring` method is public, while your `Enemigo` class is not.

You need to declare the `Enemigo` class as public:

```
public class Enemigo
```

Comment: oh wait i had to make public Enemigo and Personaje oh thank you very much you really are a lifesaver XD

Comment: No access-modifier defaults to `private` (or `internal` depending on the scope) in C#, it could be regarded as a simple safety measure so that no type or member gets unintentionally exposed should the programmer forget (contrary to Java where `public` is always the default).

Comment: WOW they DO say u can learn something new everyday thank you all xD

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Enemigo` is private in the namespace. You need to declare it as `public`.